# AngularJs Web Components using special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-component

as Web Components, I mean AngularJs's directives here.

I am trying to use special characters as a tag's name, especially asiatic ones (korean even more specifically).

Here's a [<kbd>plunker</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yqnp9fkSrSekRFGWvVWE?p=preview) so you'll get a better grasp on what I try to achieve.

```
// library
(function (angular) {

  angular.module('molecules', [])
    .directive('헐', function () { return {
      template: 'ㅎㅓㄹ'
    }});

})(window.angular);



// main module
(function (angular) {

  angular.module('lab', ['molecules']);

})(window.angular);


<div ng-controller="monitor1">
  <헐></헐>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have to do with how the browser is interpreting the DOM. If you append an alphabet character to the foreign character (in the directive and the start and end tags), it works as expected i.e.

```
<a헐></a헐>
```

Note - check out the DOM while you are at it (I was checking in IE11) - notice that the tag is closed with . With <헐> notice that the IE has taken it upon itself to make some modifications. There is also the console error HTML1407: Invalid tag name. First character should match [a-zA-Z].